# SQL numbering merge if string is the same

Tags: mysql

I want to create a stats page for my website. However I have the problem that if I run my query it will not be merged if the sting is the same. Any idea how to fix this?

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT dj_1, count(*) AS uren 
  FROM dj_rooster 
  WHERE week = '28' GROUP BY id_1 
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
) x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT dj_1, count(*) AS uren 
  FROM djpaneel_shows_uren 
  WHERE week = '28' AND active = '1' 
  GROUP BY dj_1 
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
) x
```

My results:

```
Jack - 7
Jeremy - 5
Jack - 1
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to aggregate twice or more.
Use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows from the 2 tables and then aggregate:

```
SELECT t.dj_1, COUNT(*) AS uren 
FROM (
  SELECT dj_1 FROM dj_rooster 
  WHERE week = '28' 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT dj_1 FROM djpaneel_shows_uren 
  WHERE week = '28' AND active = '1' 
) t
GROUP BY t.dj_1 
ORDER BY uren DESC
```